# Casting signed integer constant in Java

Tags: java

Simple question, I have some customised java that allows to have 32 bit HW variables.
I would like to asign such a variable a constant 32-bit value, however, this command fails
in the following scenario:

```
HWINTVar a = const.var(toHWint(32), 0xf1234567);
```

but works in this scenario:

```
HWINTVar a = const.var(toHWint(32), 0x11234567);
```

The error message in the first case is that a critical number of bits can be lost in constant values, and the reason for this is that the constants that I am passing to this method are signed. Is there a simple way how I can tell in Java to interpret this constant value as unsigned values? I tried:

```
 HWINTVar a = const.var(toHWint(32), (unsigned int) 0xf1234567);
 HWINTVar a = const.var(toHWint(32), (unsigned integer) 0xf1234567);
```

but this obvioulsy cant work in Java as it does not support unsigned data types. Any idea how this could be done?

Cheers!

Comment: Can you post the var and toHWint methods?

Comment: What gives the error message? The difference between signed and unsigned is in the interpretation of the bit pattern. The bits that are stored for 0xf1234567 are the same, whether it's a signed or an unsigned value.

Comment: If you can control `const.var`, if you're careful you can make Java treat signed ints as unsigned.  See e.g. Guava's [`UnsignedInts`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedInts.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to represent that constant correctly is as a `long` literal, i.e. `0xf1234567L`

Assuming you are able, change the definition of `const.var` so that it takes a `long` for its second parameter, and extract the bottom 32 bits to put them in your `HWINTVar`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your feedback, it works by storing the constant as long and then
use a mask for the lower 32-bits!

HWINTVar a = const.var(toHWint(32), 0xf1234567l & 0xfffffff);